# what directory is the tmp file in

Tags: boot, directory, tmp

I'm a totally overwhelmed, brand new user.

had a lot of problems during the install process while half asleep after a long day of fighting with windows and then giving up on the whole windows OS.  Anyway, i don't think I installed it properly.  I'm having trouble getting my computer to boot up from the Flash drive and without the flash drive plugged in i get no option to boot up in ubuntu.  I re-downloaded ubuntu from firefox in the trial ubuntu desktop (where i am now).

i booted up into ubuntu from a flash drive, which seems to work only about 1 out of 4 times that i boot up.  seems i have to hit F12 at exactly the correct milisecond.  i'm trying to burn the ubuntu iso to a DVD from inside this ubuntu trial version.  my windows disc burner would not burn the disk.

I re-downloaded the ubuntu iso from firefox in ubuntu.  the download just completed, and i'm trying to do the MD5SUM process according to this Link:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

problem is: the iso download is not in my downloads folder.  it went to a folder titled tmp.  firefox said something about the download being too big for the downloads folder.

i just want to go to the terminal and and run the md5sum command in the directory containing the tmp folder with the iso. i want to do that before burning the file to the DVD. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in a LiveCD environment, which is what you are referring to as a "trial" version, you are restricted only to the space available in the casper file-system, which is very small. Therefore, you cannot download the Ubuntu ISO while in a Live environment without saving it to your internal hard-drive. You will have to specify where to download the file to when Firefox prompts you as to what you wish to do with the file.

However, since you are able to boot into this Live environment, all you have to do to get Ubuntu installed is click the "Install Ubuntu" icon in the launcher on the left. This will start the Ubiquity installer. When the list of options comes up, provided you have already made a back-up of what is important to you in Windows, just choose "Erase Everything and Install" to cleanly install Ubuntu over Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I apologize that i'm uneducated and clueless.  I see the icon on the desktop, but just to be clear, i'm trying to keep both this and the windows 7 OS.  i thought i completed this process last night, and i know it partitioned my hard drive already.  don't know why i can't boot up straight into ubuntu w/o the flash drive.  Again sorry i'm a total wreck right now; microsoft/lenovo/western digital wiped out every iota of my information from my thinkpad the other day (including both back ups a 1TB external hard drive).  that's what i get for trying to disable telemetry  :/

Comment: to make matters worse, i can't seem to stay connected to wifi very long in this live environment and worse yet, i don't remember what ubuntu username i set up during the install process.  i know; very stupid of me!  i made sure to record the password, but just assumed that, like windows, ubuntu would show my username at login.

Comment: If you installed it, but did not install GRUB to the MBR, then you are still using the Windows Bootloader, BCD. You may wish to install EasyBCD on Windows so that you can edit the Windows Bootloader to include an entry for Ubuntu. There are other questions on the site detailing how to do this.

Comment: GRUB? MBR?  so many new acronyms, lol.   i'll log back into what's left of my windows 7 OS and try to get the EasyBCD program.  Thanks!

Comment: GRUB is the bootloader used by (as far as I know) all Linux distributions. MBR is the **M**aster **B**oot **R**ecord of your hard-drive. It's what is read before the partitions. If you have Windows, then BCD is in the MBR. BCD does not detect Linux installs without having been edited.

Comment: Thanks again.  i just burned a dvd without the whole md5sum process.  i want to make sure i can get back here in case I fail at installing the easyBCD program in windows.  every time i log back into windows it tries to do a disk scan process and reformat my hard drive to get rid of the partition for ubuntu.  i'm in so far over my head!  wish me luck!

Comment: took me forever but i figured out the EasyBCD program and how to make it work.  Thanks for telling me about it.  I am logged into ubuntu now (thankfully my user name was displayed at login!) As for learning my way around the ubuntu desktop and navigating ubuntu directories and knowing what directory the tmp folder is in and how to do things like an md5sum process and learning a million new terms.... well lets just say i have a very long way to go!  thankfully i'm still young, lol.

Comment: If my answer helped, remember to check the little "checkmark" next to it to say "Yes! This answer solved my problem! I accept it!" :D

Comment: just curious, is the casper file-system something that only exists in the LiveCD environment?  b/c i tried to search for it now while logged into my account, and it comes up with nothing.  just wondering.